# Would this multi-track music question be considered off-topic?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

[Where to purchase multitrack music loops?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/150230/where-to-purchase-multitrack-music-loops) was asked recently, and has seemed to have brought up confusion in Game Development. Though, to me, seems off-topic, there aren't any flag descriptions that actually match to this question.

How should this question be dealt with, if there is need for action?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally we close requests for resources, including:

- links to external websites or tutorials
- book / course recommendations
- asset sources

as off-topic, usually using the "too broad" reason.

These questions tend to attract open-ended lists of answers, where no one necessarily ranks as "correct," and the answers age poorly as links rot and old resources go out of date.

Because "too broad" doesn't explain much, if voting to close a question like this, I usually pair it with a comment explaining why our Q&A format is not an ideal fit for it, and pointing the user to GameDev.net or the chat feature here as possible routes of investigation (if the topic isn't just "Google tutorials for me so I don't have to" ;) )